# Weak to weak$^*$ continuity of the duality mapping

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-analysis, duality

Let $X$ be a uniformly convex and uniformly smooth Banach space. We consider the duality mapping $J_p^X$ defined as the sub-gradient $\partial (\frac1p\|\cdot\|^p)$. Is there a characterisation of the Banach spaces $X$ for which the mapping $J_p^X$ is weak-weak$^*$-continuous?

Let me summarise some statements I could find in the literature.
In [Xu, Roach: Characteristic inequalities of uniformly convex and uniformly smooth Banach spaces](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-247X(91)90144-O) it is shown that it is norm to weak continuous if $X$ is smooth and convex of power type $p$. On the other hand in [F. Deutsch: The alternating method of von Neumann](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-6289-9_6), the author states that $J_2^{L_p[0,1]}$ is not weak-weak$^*$-continuous for $p\neq 2$.

Comment: How lovely it would be if it were weak-weak* continuous!
In general, for non-Hilbert spaces, it is not; however, it is so for the sequence spaces.